# Error for using tensorflow on Ubuntu 14:04 with TITAN x

Tags: tensorflow, cudnn

I tried  to follow the instructions [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup.html#pip-installation) but when I import tensorflow I received this message

```
 >>> import tensorflow
  I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened    CUDA    library libcublas.so locally
  I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:99] Couldn't open CUDA library    libcudnn.so. LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local    /cuda/lib64/:/home/sal/torch/install/lib::/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64: /opt/OpenBLAS-no-openmp/lib
  I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:1562] Unable to load cuDNN DSO
  I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
  I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
  I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
```

I think I have cuda installed as I use it with caffe and Torch7 even though I tried to install it from the beginning but I kept receiving the same message.

BTW, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34770468/running-tensorflow-on-gpu-cluster-in-virtualenv) but it does not help.

Comment: You have to download cudnn also. See the steps in [the doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/get_started/os_setup.html#optional-install-cuda-gpus-on-linux)

Comment: I think I did install it

Comment: On my system I have this file `/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so`, that's where it takes it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I install new o/s then it is works, thanks