# Cuda nn path issues in installing Tensorflow gpu on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, ubuntu-16.04, nvidia, hyper-v

I am installing latest Tensorflow library in my ubuntu 16.04 machine.
For this I downloaded and Installed Latest Cuda toolkits and Cuda nn libraries.

After Installation I checked it out using following commands.

```
(/home/naseer/anaconda2/) naseer@naseer-Virtual-Machine:~/anaconda2$ python
Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:09:15) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import tensorflow as tf
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:102] Couldn't open CUDA library libcudnn.so. LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda-8.0.61/lib64
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:2259] Unable to load cuDNN DSO
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
```

What does the above output mean? does it mean that Tensorflow will correctly run on my Nvidia GPU enabled system or do I need to do something else?

**My local Directory Structure:**

I have added following screen shot that shows various library path in my local directories.

[image]

**My Understanding**

I have feeling that it is trying to open CUDA library in the path /usr/local/cuda-8.0.61/lib64 when infact there are  paths of /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64 and /usr/local/cuda/lib64. Itried to rename that path but still could not work?

**Updates (Conflicting Directory Structure)**

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running tensorflow on GPU cluster in virtualenv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34770468/running-tensorflow-on-gpu-cluster-in-virtualenv)

Comment: I have installed cuda nn and gave path of it as done in the link you suggested but it did not work.

Comment: @hbaderts I have added more specific descriptions that address my unique issue. I hope it might also help others.

Comment: What is the output of `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: sorry @hbaderts my lab is now off. I would tell you tomorrow now. thanks

Comment: @hbaderts  I did echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH and it gave  "/usr/local/cuda-8.0.61/lib64"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run TensorFlow, you *have* to install cuDNN. There are two possible ways:

#### 1. Installing cuDNN for all Users:

This is the way that the [official TensorFlow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup#optional_install_cuda_gpus_on_linux) describes.
Here, cuDNN is installed into the folder `/usr/local/cuda`. That way, cuDNN can be used by all users on that machine. The instructions are taken from the TensorFlow documentation:

1. Download the correct cuDNN version. For TensorFlow r1.1, that would be cuDNN v5.1 for CUDA 8.0.
2. Unpack the `.tgz` file. Open a terminal, navigate to the folder where you downloaded cuDNN, and call

   ```
   tar xvzf cudnn-8.0-linux-x64-v5.1-ga.tgz
   ```

   Note: this is just an example, check the file name before calling this.

   This will create a new folder called `cuda`, which contains two subfolders `include` and `lib64`, containing all cuDNN files.
3. Move the downloaded files to `/usr/local/cuda`. You will need `sudo` rights for this!

   ```
   sudo cp cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/include
   sudo cp cuda/lib64/libcudnn* /usr/local/cuda/lib64
   sudo chmod a+r /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn*
   ```

And that's already it. TensorFlow should now work as expected.

#### 2. Installing cuDNN locally:

If you do not have admin rights, or you want to have different cuDNN versions on your machine, you can install cuDNN to any folder of your choice, and then set the paths correctly. This method is proposed in [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43901888/4221706) and is explained in the official NVIDIA installation instructions.

Step 1 and 2 are the same as above.

3. Move the extracted `cuda` folder to the place you choose.
4. Add this directory to the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. In a terminal, you can do this by calling

   ```
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/cudnn/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
   ```

   where `/path/to/cudnn` is the place where you moved cuDNN in the previous step. Note the `lib64` at the end!

   Usually, you'll have to call this every time before starting TensorFlow. To avoid this, you can edit the file `~/.bashrc` and add this line at the bottom of the file. This will automatically add cuDNN to the path every time you start a terminal window.

With that, TensorFlow will be able to find cuDNN and work as expected.

Comment: thanks for your reply. A new issue that just came is that I am not able to login to my ubuntu GUI although I am able to login to command shell using ctrl+alt+f1? many forums are saying to uninstall Nvidia is that right?

Comment: No idea, sorry. Seems that something went wrong when installing the NVIDIA drivers. If you uninstall them, you won't be able to use CUDA anymore, so you might want to try to uninstall them, make sure the GUI works again, and then install the NVIDIA-drivers again.

Comment: Please also see my question updates section. My cuda folders inside the /usr/local directory and CUDA_HOME and LD-LIBRARY_PATH have different names. Should I also rename my /usr/local cuda-8.0 name to cuda-8.0.61?

Comment: Where do you create `CUDA_HOME` and  `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: I needed to rename my cuda-8.0 directory to one pointed by CUDA_HOME and LD-LIBRARY_PATH and it worked. Thanks for your time and effort. ...............regards

Comment: Good to hear. Good luck with your project

Answer (score 1):

To run a GPU enabled TensorFlow 1.4 you should first install CUDA 8 (+patch 2) and cuDNN v6.0, you may find this [step-by-step installation guide](https://technofob.com/2017/11/22/install-gpu-tensorflow-on-aws-ubuntu-16-04/) useful.

After installing the CUDA 8 drivers you will need to install cuDNN v6.0:

Download the cuDNN v6.0 driver. The driver can be downloader from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download),  please note that you will need to register first.

Copy the driver to the remote machine (scp -r -i ...)

Extract the cuDNN files, copy them to the target directory and extract the files from the .tgz file:

> tar xvzf cudnn-8.0-linux-x64-v6.0.tgz
>
> sudo cp -P cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/includesudo
>
> cp -P cuda/lib64/libcudnn* /usr/local/cuda/lib64
>
> sudo chmod a+r /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h
> /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn*

Update your bash file

> nano ~/.bashrc

Add the following lines to the end of the bash file:

> export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda
> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${CUDA_HOME}/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
> export PATH=${CUDA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}

Install the libcupti-dev library

> sudo apt-get install libcupti-dev

Install pip

> sudo apt-get install python-pip
>
> sudo pip install –upgrade pip

Install TensorFlow

> sudo pip install tensorflow-gpu

Test the installation, by running the following within the Python command line:

> from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
>
> def get_available_gpus():
>
> - local_device_protos = device_lib.list_local_devices()
> - return [x.name for x in local_device_protos if x.device_type == ‘GPU’]
>
> get_available_gpus()

For a single GPU the output should be similar to:

> 2017-11-22 03:18:15.187419: I
> tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports
> instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use:
> SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
>
> 2017-11-22 03:18:17.986516: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:892] successful
> NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be
> at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
>
> 2017-11-22 03:18:17.986867: I
> tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1030] Found device 0
> with properties:
>
> name: Tesla K80 major: 3 minor: 7 memoryClockRate(GHz): 0.8235
>
> pciBusID: 0000:00:1e.0
>
> totalMemory: 11.17GiB freeMemory: 11.10GiB
>
> 2017-11-22 03:18:17.986896: I
> tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1120] Creating
> TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0) -> (device: 0, name: Tesla K80, pci
> bus id: 0000:00:1e.0, compute capability: 3.7)
>
> [u’/device:GPU:0′]